# Java: Adding multiple user input coordinates to a list

Tags: java

I am writing a Java program to take user input of coordinates such as:

`((1 2),(3 4))`

and put it into a list of coordinates. So for example if I input `((3 2))` I would strip all the parenthesis and split the string on the comma so that the two coordinates are put into an ArrayList as:

```
[1 2, 3 4]
```

I am able to strip all the parenthesis if I have a single coordinate (i.e. `((1 2))`) but how would I got about splitting a string and putting each unique coordinate as it's own entry in an ArrayList?

Here is my code so far:

```
    public static String getParenthesesContent(String str){
        String answer = str.substring(str.indexOf("((")+2,str.indexOf(")"));
        return answer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> points = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter coordinates: ");

        String blocks = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(blocks);

        String answer = getParenthesesContent(blocks);
        System.out.println(answer);

        points.add(answer);
   }
```

Comment: please share your code so far

Comment: not much clear. can we see the code with your try?

Comment: Try splitting on the comma first and then stripping the parentheses of each element. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: All those parenthesis add nothing it seems, strip them all, then just split on the comma.

Comment: Do you need a string in the list or a pair of coordinates? "1 2" or (1, 2)?

Comment: A string of "1 2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a more easy and better way to define inputs in order to process that input better/faster/easier (it looks like you are shooting yourself on the foot with that input format)

to the question... you can define REGEX with a pattern like **`\\((.+?)\\)`**
and clean every match and after that put it into the list.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    List<String> points = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Enter coordinates: ");

    String blocks = "((1 2),(3 4))";
    foo(blocks, points);
    blocks = "( 1 2)"; //intentionally added space to the input
    foo(blocks, points);
    blocks = "((1 2),(3 4),(8 7))";
    foo(blocks, points);
    System.out.println(points);

}

private static void foo(final String blocks, final List<String> points) {
    Matcher match = Pattern.compile("\\((.+?)\\)").matcher(blocks);
    while (match.find()) {
        String x = match.group(1).replace("(", "").trim();

        System.out.println(x);
        points.add(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the split method [split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), to divide the input and then get rid of the parentheses and add to the list.

```
List<String> points = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter coordinates: ");

    String blocks = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(blocks);
    String[] vars= blocks.split(",");
     for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        String answer = getParenthesesContent(vars[i]);
        if(!points.contains(answer)) points.add(answer);//prevent repeat
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points.toArray()));
```

**OUPUT**

```
[1 2, 3 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using these coordinates often you could also create a Position class to hold (x,y) and save the position objects in ArrayList.

```
public class Position {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Position(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() { return x; }
    public int getY() { return y; }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Could be handy if you would like to extend Comparable to sort them easily or such, or want methods like:

```
this.getX();
```

or

```
this.getPosition();
```

You could also add the positions to a HashMap and store the position of different objects.

```
HashMap<Position, Object> hMap = new HashMap<>();
hMap.put(new Position(1,3), player);
```